# Why are base64Encode images being loaded before content on my website?

Tags: html, base64, malware

While performing a waterfall performance test with Pingdom, I discovered about 10 base64Encode images being loaded before any other page elements loaded. This is an HTML/CSS/JS web site. I could not find any code or tag referring to these images loading. I am concerned it was placed by Malware.

Website: www.graymatterimages.com
first two of 10 images being loaded:
data:text/html,chromewebdata
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA…
[ rest are data:image/png ]

Where did they come from and should I be concerned?

Comment: After actually looking at those images, it seems that they are in fact the images that take part of the Chrome page itself (the little dinosaur, the cactus, the broken page). I tried other pages and could not see that, I manually ran a Chrome timeline on your side and don't see it either. I'm leaning towards a problem with PingDom itself, but I can't explain why it  happens with your site specifically.

Comment: Thanks Alpha. You are correct, those are Chrome specific images. I ran the same Pingdom performance test (tools.pingdom.com) using FireFox and those URI images were not in the waterfall element list. --- Seems to be the specific combination of that web site with Chrome. One possible explaination: I also have the site registered with Pingdom monitoring.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. If that's the case, you should report it to them. If you can confirm that was in fact the problem, you could answer your own question with what you found out -- it'd be the right answer to this problem.

Comment: Thanks @Alpha -- I had the same problem and couldn't figure out why I recognized those images. Your comment jarred my memory that they were from Chrome. Cheers!

Comment: @TheDavidJohnson I'm glad it helped. If so, do you have details on how to reproduce? I'd like to report the issue to the PingDom team. Happy new year 2018!

Comment: @Alpha I wish I did. All I can say is that I ran a PingDom test from a Chrome browser. Repeating didn't reproduce the problem. Also other users attempted to do the same thing from other machines and didn't get the issue again. I should mention that the site in question was having intermittent "connection reset" and similar networking problems at the hosting provider, so I'm inclined to believe that's where the problem originated. We moved hosting and it seems to be resolved.